# nginx limit_req works не работает и отдает 404

Tags: nginx

Доброго времени суток.

Возникла проблема с nginx.

В секции http

```
limit_req_status 403;
limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr  zone=two:10m rate=5r/m;
```

в хосте sites-available

```
location /api/public/symbols {  limit_req zone=two nodelay; }
```

В итоге домен.ком/api/public/symbols отдается 404 до тех пор, пока не превысим количество запросов (т.е. контента нет). Если закомментить записи - всё работает. С чем может быть связано?

фулл конфиги https://pastebin.com/XdHXWA53 и https://pastebin.com/1xcdM1zC

Comment: покажи адрес на который ты обращаешься и получаешь 404

Comment: напишите, пожалуйста, id26327371@mail.ru или телеграмм t.me/emobort т.к. не афишируется проект.

Comment: замени начало на что угодно. хочется понять в какой location запрос попадал раньше, в какой сейчас.

Comment: к сожалению. всё безрезультатно, мучаюсь второй день. Если есть возможность. напишите. пожалуйста. сброшу все ссылки.

Comment: как думаешь, оно мне надо?

Answer (score -1):

А зачем Вы меняете стандартный код 503 на 403 ?

403 у вас может отдавать само web приложение

Сделайте в server { }

```
error_page 503 =429 @blacklist;
```

и определите отдельный локейшн для обработки превышения лимитов конекта, типа

```
location @blacklist {
}
```

Comment: судя по конфигу до "web-приложения" дело не доходит и, судя по конфигу, там тупо срабатывает `root` и поиск в каталоге результатом даёт 404

Comment: так должно выглядеть, верно?
location @blacklist {
limit_req zone=one nodelay;
limit_req zone=two nodelay;
limit_req zone=three nodelay;
}

Comment: В location @blacklist предназначен для обработки ошибки превышения лимитов, в нем вы можете сделать например отдельную страничку с выводом предупреждения, типа "Превышено максимально допустимое количество запросов с вашего IP" или сделать там вызов внешнего скрипта для блокировки нарушителя или передать обработку запроса на другой сервер.